# parse.com Implement local storage with relational objects

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement parse local storage mechanism like described in this **[link](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore)**.
The only change I made was adding a new object called "comment" (Toledo has many comments, comment object has a pointer to his todo).

Because the ObjectId was not generated yet (it only generated while saving the object to parse servers), I can't save a comment with the todo pointer into the my local storage, because the pointer relation based on the ObjectId.

I can use the UUID field like described in the tutorial, but then I won't be able to use pointer relations.

There is a way to generate ObjectId? Or any other way to make it work?